# C++ Vector implementation allocating new objects

Tags: c++, class, memory, memory-management, vector

I'm almost done with the implementation of a std::vector type of vector (hopefully) but I'm having a little bug in the code and I can't seem to find where. Basically when I build Vector and use push_back, the vector automatically allocates new memory for more elements (specifically twice the size of the vector) but when doing so, the "extra space" is initialized to 0's and I don't know why.

Here is my code:

**Vector.h**

```
#include <memory>
#include <cstddef>

template <class T>
class Vec{
    public:
        typedef T* iterator;
        typedef const T* const_iterator;
        typedef size_t size_type;
        typedef T value_type;

        Vec(){create();}
        Vec(size_type n, const T& val = T()) {create(n, val);}

        ~Vec() {uncreate();}

        //copy constructor
        Vec(const Vec& v) {create(v.begin(), v.end());}
        //assignment operator
        Vec& operator=(const Vec&);

        size_type size() const {return limit - data;}

        //index operators
        T& operator[](size_type i) {return data[i];}
        const T& operator[](size_type i) const {return data[i];}

        iterator begin() {return data;}
        const_iterator begin() const {return data;}

        iterator end() {return limit;}
        const_iterator end() const {return limit;}

        void push_back(const T&);


    private:
        iterator data; //1st element
        iterator avail; //one past last constructed element
        iterator limit; //one past last available element

        //Memory management
        std::allocator<T> alloc;

        void create();
        void create(size_type, const T&);
        void create(const_iterator, const_iterator);

        void uncreate();

        void grow();
        void unchecked_append(const T&);

};

template <class T>
void Vec<T>::push_back(const T& val){
    if(avail == limit)
        grow();
    unchecked_append(val);
}

template <class T>
Vec<T>& Vec<T>::operator=(const Vec& rhs){
    //self-assign
    if(&rhs != this){
        uncreate;
        create(rhs.begin(), rhs.end());
    }
    return *this;
}

// Empty Vector, pointers to 0
template <class T> void Vec<T>::create(){
    data = avail = limit = 0;
}

// Allocate memory for (size)
template <class T> void Vec<T>::create(size_type n, const T& val){
    data = alloc.allocate(n); // returns pointer to first element
    limit = avail = data +n;
    std::uninitialized_fill(data, limit, val);
}

template <class T> void Vec<T>::create(const_iterator i, const_iterator j){
    data = alloc.allocate(j-i);
    limit = avail =std::uninitialized_copy(i, j, data);
}

template <class T> void Vec<T>::uncreate(){
    if(data){
        iterator it = avail;
        while(it != data)
            alloc.destroy(--it);

        // Free space
        alloc.deallocate(data, limit - data);
    }
    // Empty Vector
    data = limit = avail = 0;
}

template <class T> void Vec<T>::grow(){
    // Allocate twice the space we had
    size_type new_size = std::max(2 * (limit - data), ptrdiff_t(1));

    // Allocate new space and copy to new space
    iterator new_data = alloc.allocate(new_size);
    iterator new_avail = std::uninitialized_copy(data, avail, new_data);

    // Return old space used
    uncreate();

    // Reset pointers to point to new space
    data = new_data;
    avail = new_avail;
    limit = data + new_size;
}

template <class T> void Vec<T>::unchecked_append(const T& val){
    alloc.construct(avail++, val);
}
```

And this is how I created the vector

**main.cpp**

```
#include "vector.h"
#incude <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    Vec<int> v1;
    v1.push_back(12);
    v1.push_back(9);
    v1.push_back(74);
    v1.push_back(22);
    Vec<int> v2 = v1;  
    v2.push_back(70); //After doing this the vector is (12, 9, 74, 22, 70, 0, 0, 0)
    for(auto e: v2) cout << e << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
```

Thanks for any help and also any feedback on the actual code is appreciated. :)

Comment: Maybe your `std::allocator` always does this, have you checked? Maybe it does it in debug builds, is this one? Have you tried just stepping through your `grow` method seeing what the new data looks like at each step?

Comment: I dont get your comment, how can v2 have more than one element in it? You only added 70? Or is it that 70 ends up in v1?

Comment: Had a typo, edited it. Im initializing it from v1.

Comment: @Useless not sure actually. I only check that the std::vector doesnt do that, so maybe theres a bug in my code or im missing something/did something extra.

Comment: I just gave you a list of things to check, so check them! You have the code for your allocator installed locally, so read it. You know (or should be able to find) your build settings & compiler documentation. You have, presumably, a debugger, so use it.

Comment: Im on it right now. I havnt setup my debugger yet. I've been on c++ for just 3 days and im a vim user so not built in. Do you know of a good debugger for linux perhaps?

Comment: @Useless I've checked the std functions im using but im not seeing any assignments done by any of them.  They all leave the space uninitialized

Comment: I just use gdb, because it's everywhere, but ddd provides a slightly friendlier wrapper

Comment: @Useless im using gdb but I cant seem to find anything...

Comment: Allright figured it out. My end() function was passing the "limit" variable instead of the "avail" which is what std::vector does I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is (i do not know if it is really  problem)

```
template <class T> void Vec<T>::grow(){
    // Allocate twice the space we had
    size_type new_size = std::max(2 * (limit - data), ptrdiff_t(1));
....
....
}
```

No need to do any vector copy to reproduce your problem.

The problem can be seen even in first vector after inserting 5th elemnt

```
    v1.push_back(12);
    v1.push_back(9);
    v1.push_back(74);
    v1.push_back(22);
    v1.push_back(22);  //5th elemnt.
```

now printing the size;

```
cout<<v1.size()<<endl; - it says 8.
```

Even the std vector, after resize(), it is normal behavior to print zeros for the empty elements.

Look at this example:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize

if you do not want additional zeros, you have to tweak your ":new_size" calculation.

Comment: Yes. I meant to do that new_size calculation. My error was just passing the wrong variable from the class. I was passing "limit" instead of "avail". Limit is one past the end for the whole array (including the allocated memory). Avail is one past the end the last initialized value.

Comment: There it is. Good.